# Find how many random points lie inside ellipse centered at a point

Tags: python, list, loops, numpy

The below code generates set of random x,y coordinates and uses the equation of an ellipse to compare how many of those points lie inside ellipse centered at (1,1) and a rectangle of area 2a*2b constructed around the ellipse whose semimajor and semiminor axis are a and b but b is variable and takes a value from the list b every single time. I want to have all the values of b for which the ratio of all the points lying inside the ellipse to the points lying inside the rectangle is greater than 0.5.

The problem I'm facing is If I check for a single value of b = 0.63. the condition ellipse_points/rectangle_points is approximately equal to 0.5 but when I loop throught the list b and use the If statement to get all the points for which ellipse_points/rectangle_points > 0.5, I do not see any value close to 0.63 instead I see values from 1.2 till 1.9, I do not understand why when I loop through a list of values for b the if statement seems to give faulty values. please refer to the next set of code where I set value of b = 0.63 and find ratio ellipse_points/rectangle_points

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(0, 2, 10000) #generates random x coordinates
y = np.random.uniform(0, 2, 10000) #generates random y coordinates 
ellipse_points, rectangle_points = 0, 0
a = 1
b = []
for i in range(1, 200):
    b.append(i/100)
#print(b)

for p in b:
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        if (((i - 1) ** 2) / a ** 2 + ((j - 1) ** 2) / p ** 2) < 1:
            ellipse_points += 1
        rectangle_points += 1
    if ellipse_points/rectangle_point > 0.5:
        print(p)
```

OUTPUT: 1.2, 1.21.............1.9

#

```
x = np.random.uniform(0, 2, 10000) #generates random x coordinates
y = np.random.uniform(0, 2, 10000) #generates random y coordinates 
ellipse_points, rectangle_points = 0, 0
a = 1
b = 0.63

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    if (((i - 1) ** 2) / a ** 2 + ((j - 1) ** 2) / b ** 2) < 1:
        ellipse_points += 1
    rectangle_points += 1
print(ellipse_points/rectangle_points)
```

OUTPUT 0.5001

Comment: yes, I corrected it. thx!

Comment: Don't you want to reset `ellipse_points` and `rectangle_points` each time you change `p`?

Comment: Yes, That's correct. That answers the question!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: you can also just do `b=sqrt(sorted((y-1)*(y-1)/x/(2-x))[5000])` which is  `(0.63 # 2/pi)`. No loop on `b` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, here's a vectorized solution.

It creates a binary mask for points inside the ellipse, counts where the mask is `True` and divides it by the total number of points.

```
# np.random.seed(42)
N = 10000
x = np.random.uniform(0, 2, N) #generates random x coordinates 
y = np.random.uniform(0, 2, N) #generates random y coordinates

a = 1
b = 0.63

ratio = ((((x - 1)/a)**2 + ((y - 1)/b)**2) < 1).sum()/N

>>> print(ratio)
0.4954
```